# How to determine the homology groups of $\{(v,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid vw \neq 0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I want to determine the homology groups of $\{(v,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid vw \neq 0\}$. I googled this problem and found that there's a general theory called arrangements of hyperplanes. But this theory is quite involved. So I'm wondering if there's some simpler way to do this.

I was considering Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I was sort of confused. Since $\{(v,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2|vw \neq 0\}$ is the complement of two complex planes, I need to find an open cover with good intersections. But I don't know how to do this. Can anyone enlighten me or give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: $\Bbb C^2 - \{z=0\}$ deformation retracts to $|z|=\varepsilon$, which is $S^1\times\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So $\mathbb{C}^2-\{ v=0\}-\{ w=0\}$ deformation retracts to $\{ S^1 \vee S^1\} \times \mathbb{C}$? I'm not sure since $\mathbb{C}^2$ is sort of difficult for me to imagine.

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. You have those two intersecting cylinders and you have to remove the stuff "near the origin." So you ought to be able to deformation retract to something more tractable.

Comment: It deformation retracts onto its intersection with $S^3$, the set of points where $v^2+w^2=1$. Can you figure out what taking the intersection deletes from $S^3$? And can you translate that to a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Define the map $\Gamma:X \to X$ by $\Gamma(v,w)=(\frac{v}{|v|}, \frac{w}{|w|})$. This is a continues map as a composition of continues maps. This is a deformation retraction by the homotopy:
$$t (\frac{v}{|v|}, \frac{w}{|w|})+(1-t)(v,w)$$
By direct calculation you can show that for $t \in [0,1]$ the norm of each coordinate is different then $0$. This shows that the homotopy is well defined. Let the retract subspace be $A$ then observe that it’s homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$. Now compute this by Kunneth if you know, else you can use a  Mayer-Vietoris but it’s harder.

To make this answer more complete here is how you can compute the torus($S^1 \times S^1$) using Mayer-Vietoris. Fi[image: The sets U &V]
I will Cover the Torus by 2 Open sets of the Torus $A=U$ and $B=V$ as seen in the figure }. Observe that $U$ and $V$ are cylinders and by the retraction trick their homology groups are the same as $S^1$. Hence will get:

$$H_n(V)=H_n(U)= \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & \text{if}\ n=0,1 \\
0          & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Observe that $U \cap V$ is a disjoint union of $S^1$ so by the following theorem :

Corresponding to the decomposition of a space $X$ into its path components
$X_\alpha $there is an isomorphism of $H_n(X)$ with the direct sum $\oplus_\alpha X_\alpha $.
\

We get: $$H_n(U \cap V)= \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} & \text{if}\ n=0,1 \\
0          & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
So by Mayer-Vietoris the following sequence is exact ( $i,j$ be the inclusions from $U \cap V$  to $U ,V$ $k,l$  and  be the inclusions from $U,V$ to  the torus):
$$\dots \longrightarrow H_n(U)\oplus H_n(V) \longrightarrow H_n(S^1 \times S^1) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(U \cap V) \longrightarrow \dots $$
So for $n > 2 $ We immediately have $H_n(S^1 \times S^1)=0$. For $n=2$ We have the sequence:
$$\dots 0 \longrightarrow H_2(S^1 \times S^1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \dots $$
Observe that $H(U) \cong H(v) \cong \mathbb{Z} $  $a$ and $b$ are different basis element in homology class  $U \cap V$ they will be both sent to the same homology class element in the inclusion function. So the kernel of $(i_*, j_*)$ in the exact sequence is $<a-b>$. This is an exact sequence and the image to $H_2(S^1 \times S^1)$ is $\{0\}$ so the Kernal from $H_2(S^1 \times S^1)$ is $\{0\}$. This implies that $H_2(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}<a-b> \cong \mathbb{Z} $. \
As for $n=1$ the Mayer-Vietoris sequence will be:
$$\dots \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{(i_*, j_*)}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{k_* - l_*}{\longrightarrow} H_1(S^1 \times S^1) \stackrel{\partial}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}  \stackrel{(i_* , j_*)}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}   \longrightarrow \dots $$
So we get a short exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow \mathrm{ker}\ \partial \longrightarrow H_1(S^1 \times S^1) \longrightarrow
\mathrm{Im}\ \partial 
\longrightarrow 0$$
Now $\mathrm{Im}\ \partial = \mathrm{Ker}\ (i_* , j_*)$ which we have seen that is $\mathbb{Z}$. To compute $\mathrm{Ker}\ \partial$ We use:
$$\mathrm{ker}\ \partial = \mathrm{Im}\ (k_*-l_*) =(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}) / \mathrm{Ker}(k_*-l_* ) = (\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/\mathrm{Im}(i_*, j_*) = \mathbb{Z}$$
Using the fact that the long sequence is exact for the identity's in the formula.\
So we Get:
$$H_1(S^1 \times S^1)/ \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$$
This implies that $H_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $
For $n=0$ we know that the torus is connected so $H_0(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $S^1\times S^1$ is a CW-complex, so its homology may be computed with cellular homology

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you and Miller have suggested. By considering stereographic projection, we may map $S^3-\{ (v,w)|v=0, |w|=1\}-\{ (v,w)|w=0, |v|=1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. This case is easy to calculate. But when the complex planes get more, say $\{v=0 \}$, $\{w=0 \}$ and $\{v=w \}$, the calculation becomes harder and it's hard to see through. Could you please give me some further suggestions?

Comment: I will gladly give further suggestions but for what? Did you understand why you only need to calculate the Homology of $S^1 \times S^1$ to compute the Homology of your space? Is your problem calculating $H_n(S^1 \times S^1)$?